# Can't achieve padding in menu items using sIFR 3

Tags: sifr, padding

n00b question alert, but I've been struggling for a few days with this one and have searched in vain for the solution in other posts!

I have a horizontal menu that has padding either side of the text such that the items appear separated. However upon replacing the text with sIFR, the padding doesn't appear, and thus the items all look like they are separated by only a space (and it looks like they are all within the same flash movie). I need to separate them!

The css is set as so:

```
#menu a {
height: 30px;
padding: 8px 38px;
letter-spacing: -1px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 22px;
color: #000000;
}
```

I've tried putting the same in the sifr.css at the bottom:

```
.sIFR-active #menu { 
padding: 8px 38px;
visibility: hidden;
font-family: Verdana;
font-size: 19px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

That doesn't work. I've tried putting this into the sIFR.replace function too, as well as a few other directives like tuneWidth... I haven't managed to get this working no matter what I try! Can anyone help?

If you want to have a look at an example page go here: http://www.ak40.co.uk/invitation.htm

Many thanks in advance.

Kev

Answer (score 0):

Put some margin around the Flash movies instead.